Flutter background_fetch
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://jitpack.io/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
       - file:/Users/rhaynelsillador/Documents/projects/moonshot/alarm/android/app/libs/com/transistorsoft/tsbackgroundfetch/maven-metadata.xml
     Required by:
         project :app > project :background_fetch

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Anyone can help? Always shows this error every time I run my Flutter app?
I installed background_fetch and got this error when running the Android app.
When I check the repositories link I got 404.

This question is similar to: Flutter - Could not find any matches for com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:+ as no versions of com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch are available. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is a problem with initial configuration of this plugin, which is described here: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md#open_file_folder-androidbuildgradle
Essentially, package needs you to add repository. You should modify your root build.gradle like this:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs" } 
    }
}

Also, I would recommend to follow other instructions in background_fetch's documentation
